# The command "./run-ab-platform.sh" in Windows PowerShell does not execute

Tags: docker, image, containers, docker-desktop, airbyte

I have been trying to install airbyte in Docker Desktop using the following instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte.git
cd airbyte
./run-ab-platform.sh
```

The problem is that the command `./run-ab-platform.sh` does not execute. It just opens the script. The Windows Powershell should execute the command and this command should install many containers and images in Docker Desktop.

I have already uninstalled the Docker Desktop and make all the process again, but I still with the same problem.

Does anyone know how can I proceed?

Best regards.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Running script files with the .sh extension will not be executed in Windows PowerShell - these files typically have a .ps1 extension. Looking at the ./run-ab-platform.sh, the first line has "#!/bin/bash" which tells me it's a bash script.

Comment: Hey Skyhammer! Now it works. I was in the PowerShell and I put "bash" and after this I was in the Linux system. I went at airbyte folder and finally the command ./run-ab-platform.sh works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a Bash script. You can tell [from the first line](https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/blob/master/run-ab-platform.sh#L1) where it specifies the interpreter. Powershell is a different shell entirely. You need to run it [from in WSL](https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/blob/ae30ce09de3f0974fccbba3482ab647fc42e806c/docs/deploying-airbyte/local-deployment.md?plain=1#L38).

Comment: Hey, Zac. Now it works. I was in the PowerShell and I put "bash" and after this I was in the Linux  system. I went at airbyte folder and finally the command ./run-ab-platform.sh works! Thanks!